# iphone developer: no identity found

Tags: iphone, xcode

My development machine suddenly decided to stop installing to my device this morning, with the codesign process giving the error "no identify found".

I checked my keychain and my developer certificate is there, valid until 2012.

The only links I've found in google talk about developing on a jailbroken phone, which I don't have.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure your provisioning file didn't expire?

Comment: None of my provisioning profiles expire before July

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the build settings for the "target" try reselecting the code signing identity. This often happens when working with more than one developer or if you recently added devices to the provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

If any of your Provisioning Profiles expired, update them. If this is not the case, go to your project settings, there you should be able to find the codesign and a bunch of other useful stuff. Change it to the correct one, not the "iphonedeveloper" - **the one that has your name in it!**